# Issue when exporting SVG with a gradient from Sketch App

Tags: css, svg, sketchapp

I have an issue when I export SVGs from Sketch, the gradient looks different in all browsers than it is in Sketch. The problem is in the gradient direction, it's totally opposite. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Sketch:

[image: sketch screenshot]

Chrome:

[image: chrome screenshot]

Comment: 1. First report the bug to Sketch.  2. Load the SVG into a text editor and adjust the gradient definition.  You probably need to modify the `x2` and `y2` attributes of the gradient.  I can't really give better instructions than that without seeing the SVG file.

Answer (score -1):

### ----------

Hello, this might be due the display profile set in your system preferences that states how your monitor interprets color. You can change it in this part of your settings:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3Exj.png)